# Switch values in a linked list (dealing with nodes)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm writing a method to switch a pair of value in a linked list.

For example, my list contains:

```
1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 3
```

after the method call, the list should contains:

```
4, 1, 8, 5, 3, 9
```

dealing with linked list is confusing me by using nodes only, and i don't understand why my code only switch the first 2 values in the list.  Any ideas?  A little more explanation would be great. Thank you.

```
public void switchPairs() {
    ListNode current = front;
    ListNode temp = front.next;
    while(current.next != null) {
        int i = front.data;
        front.data = front.next.data;
        front.next.data = i;

        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `ListNode` variable names to `first` and `second`, and it will be easier to spot the issues.  You don't properly swap nor do you properly iterate both `ListNodes`.  You must iterate both by 2.

```
public void switchPairs() {
    ListNode first = front;//first node in pair
    ListNode second = front.next;//second node in pair

    //while the both nodes are not null
    while(first != null && second != null) {
        int i = first.data;//put first value in temp value
        first.data = second.data;//put second value in first node
        second.data = i;//put temp value (first value) in second node

        //NOTE:  do some null pointer checks here just in case
        first = second.next;//iterate first node
        second = second.next.next;//iterate second node
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not altering the front value. All the time the front alters between the first and the second number . But as the current is set to front initially, each time current value gets incremented till it reaches thd last value